# MathJax tries to render "side-by-side markdown" when Fast Preview is enabled

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I have enabled "fast preview" in the MathJax context menu "Math Settings $\to$ Math Renderer $\to$ Fast Preview", MathJax will attempt to render formulas in the "side-by-side markdown" comparison view for edit histories and suggested edits. This view is otherwise supposed to show raw unrendered source (and does so without fast preview enabled).

This error only shows when "side-by-side markdown" is the preferred mode *when the page loads*. It looks correct if I switch from "inline" to "side-by-side markdown" *after* the page load, but reappears if I then reload the page.

Here's how a [random example](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1092913/revisions) looks for me (Firefox 35.0.5, Windows 7) with Fast Preview enabled:
[image: screenshot goes here]
Note that the red/green highlighting seems to confuse MathJax into losing sync of the beginning/ending dollar signs.

This behavior doesn't show in Chrome 39 or IE 11.

Comment: In your example, the side-by-side markdown view shows as you want it for me, completely unrendered, plain source. Can you add a screenshot of how it looks for you?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Screenshot added.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Upon further experimentation it looks like I only get this behavior because I've turned on "fast preview" in the MathJax settings. That makes for a somewhat different bug report; will edit.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xmE9P.png) is how it looks for me (SeaMonkey 2.31, openSuSE 12.3). I also have turned on "Fast Preview" in the MathJax settings, so it's not that (alone). Could be the browser or OS, let me take a look in other browsers.

Comment: Also fine in Konqueror and Firefox 34.0.5, with the same MathJax settings. Can you check in other browsers?

Comment: @DanielFischer: It shows up correctly when I _switch to_ "side-by-side markdown" from one of the other views. It seems the bug appears only when "side-by-side markdown" is the initial view at page load time. Bug does not appear with Chrome or IE.

Comment: Indeed, when I load the page with side-by-side markdown as the preferred view, I get it too.

Answer (score 3):

Pages can control what parts are processed by MathJax using the class `tex2jax_ignore`; the contents of any container element that has this class will not be processed by MathJax.  SE uses this to prevent the difference section from being processed by MathJax.

Unfortunately, the `tex2jax_ignore` class seems to be added dynamically to the page after it arrives at the browser (the original HTML page doesn't have the class in it, and it looks like `revisions.en.js` includes code to add the `tex2jax_ignore` class).  It appears that there is a race condition between `revisions.en.js` and MathJax: if MathJax runs first, then the `tex2jax_ignore` class will not have been applied yet, and the differences will be processed by MathJax, but if `revisions.en.js` runs first, then the class will be in place when MathJax runs, and it will ignore the difference section.

It turns out that this has nothing to do with the fast preview, and more to do with the SE configuration and the timing of files as they arrive at the browser.  I managed to see the math rendered once (the first time I viewed the page, presumably because I had MathJax in cache, but not the revisions file), but haven't been able to get it to do so again, regardless of the setting of the fast preview.

It would be better if SE had `tex2jax_ignore` in the original HTML file rather than adding it later.  Alternatively, they could configure `tex2jax` to use the `markdown-diff` class as one of the classes to be ignored (like `tex2jax_ignore`) rather than adding `tex2jax_ignore` after the page is loaded.